# Print Statement using two data types

Tags: python

```
print("this is your "+t+" warning")
```

t is supposed to be an integer.

this is probably a silly and stupid question but is it possible to print a variable(in the case t with an int value) and a string("this is your" & "warning") together in one print statement[print()].

If I remember it correctly it's possible in java, not sure though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
name="John"
band="Sykler"
print("The band for", name, "is", band, "out of 10")
```

Comment: A good answer will always include an explanation why this would solve the issue, so that the OP and any future readers can learn from it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use string formatting to pass your print statement as one string.

```
print(f"this is your {t} warning")
```

In case if you would like to get familiar with string formatting: https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/

Answer (score 1):

```
t = 0
print("this is your", t, "warning")
print(f"this is your {t} warning")
print("this is your " + str(t) + " warning")
print("this is your %d warning" % t)
print("this is your %s warning" % str(t))
# to decide how many numbers after the dot change x in this '%.xf' to the number of numbers after the dot
print("this is your %.3f warning" % float(t))
```

Answer (score 1):

yes it is. you can pass multiple values to the print function and each gets printed

```py
print("test", 2, ['something'])
```

Answer (score 1):

in python, `+` with string types will work as concatenation. If you use different data types, it will give you `TypeError can only concatenate str (not "int") to str`.

So you need to use `,` to concatenate different types:

```
t= 10
print("this is your",t,"Test")
```